# How to get CodeChef IDE to read from standard input?

Tags: c, scanf

I thought while using scanf on a character sometimes caused it to be skipped. However, I'm trying to use the function on an integer and it's not working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n1, n2, d1, d2, rn, rd;
    printf("Enter first fraction\n");
    scanf("%d/%d", &n1, &d1);

    printf("Enter second fraction\n");
    scanf("%d/%d", &n2, &d2);

    rn = n1*d2 + n2*d1;
    rd = d1*d2;

    printf("The result is %d/%d\n", rn, rd);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Enter first fraction
Enter second fraction
The result is 1835042429/-1042310836
```

Comment: But what's the input?

Comment: It doesn't give me a chance to input anything. It skips over the scanf()'s and just outputs.

Comment: If this code quietly skips `scanf`, it means that either the standard input is redirected or somethig is seriously broken in the run-time library or host system.

Comment: I'd guess that some leftover data is sitting in the standard input. Is this the complete code, or just a snippet extracted from a larger program?

Comment: It's the complete code. I'm compiling on this online C compiler https://www.codechef.com/ide I'm running the GCC 4.9.2 option from the drop-dwon list

Comment: Er... What? Online compiler?! Online compilers will **not** stop and wait for your input. If you want to use standard input with that online compiler, you have to click "Custom input" and enter everything in advance. E.g. you have to type something like `1/2 3/4` into the "Custom input" box *before* running the program.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you use `scanf()`, you must check the return value to verify if input was correctly parsed into the destination arguments.  This will tell you if you have invalid or missing input that causes hard to find bugs:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n1, n2, d1, d2, rn, rd;

    printf("Enter first fraction\n");
    if (scanf("%d/%d", &n1, &d1) != 2) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter second fraction\n");
    if (scanf("%d/%d", &n2, &d2) != 2) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    rn = n1 * d2 + n2 * d1;
    rd = d1 * d2;

    printf("The result is %d/%d\n", rn, rd);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** You are running your code on https://www.codechef.com/ide : unless you check the **Custom input** option, and provide actual input, standard input is an empty file.  You cannot run a program interactively on this site, you should install a compiler (and a debugger) on you own system to learn programming more effectively.

Comment: Thanks. I tried what you wrote, and it gives the invalid input message and stops after the first if statement. However, I'm not inputting anything. Why is it telling me invalid input?

Comment: What operating system? (shouldn't matter, but I've seen stranger things come out of windoze)

Comment: Windsos. If it helps, I'm compiling on this website https://www.codechef.com/ide with the GCC 4.9.2 option in the drop-down list.

Comment: Your program runs with standard input redirected from /dev/null.

Comment: Ok. How do I get it to accept standard input from the keyboard?

Comment: Check the **Custom input** option next to the run button.